# How to handle File Upload in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I have excel importer in my application when I click on the "Upload" button I will get a pop up window with file upload screen where I can select the excel from the specified path. How to handle this in Robot Framework?  Can any one help me how to handle the case?

Answer (score 2):

Selenium2Library provides [`Choose File`](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Choose%20File) keyword for the same.

It takes two arguments, first is locator for the button and second is path to the file which needs to be uploaded.

e.g.

```
Choose File xpath=.//div/input  ${TEMPDIR}${/}file_pa.csv
```

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged here because the links may become dead in the future. I suggest you edit your answer with quotes from the sources you cite

Comment: You can upload a file using "Choose File" Keyword, but you need to find locator that has a property "input".

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a dialog or input that WebDriver can interact with, then Sachin's answer about `Choose File` is the way to go.

If you're talking about the pre-HTML5 file-chooser dialogs provided by the browser, then Selenium2Library can't do this. However RobotFramework isn't just a wrapper around Selenium2Library so you can use something else that allows you to interact with the file upload screen.

I've done it in the past using [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/).

If you're not explicitly testing the upload dialog (and why should you, since it's provided as an atomic widget by your browser) then you should consider ways to simply avoid it. Perhaps a simple rest interface for uploading files.